# Raspberry Pi direct wiring connection problem

Tags: wiring, breadboard

I wrote some code to activate a video when a motion sensor detects movement.
So far everything works while everything is wired to the breadboard.

When I connect my motion sensor to the Pi itself, it keeps triggering itself even when there is no motion.
Any idea what could be wrong?
The sensor is connected to GPIO4. When I wire the cables directly on the Raspberry on the corresponding pins the trouble starts.
Do I have to change something in my code when directly wiring to the Pi?

Thanks in advance for any kind of help.

Below my code and config code also and a picture of my breadboard setup and the setup when it's wired direcly to the Pi.

[image]
[image]
[image]

```
from gpiozero import MotionSensor, LED, Button
from time import sleep
import vlc
playing = set([1,2,3,4])  

# creating Instance class object
vlc_instance = vlc.Instance()
  
player = vlc_instance.media_player_new()
player.set_fullscreen(True)
  
#Motion Sensor
pir = MotionSensor(4)
#Led
led = LED(26)
#Button
button= Button(18)
led.off()
print("Sensor wordt geladen.")
pir.wait_for_no_motion()
sleep(5)

while True:
    print("Ready")
    pir.wait_for_motion()
    sleep(1)
    print("Motion detected")
    led.on()
    sleep(1)
    led.off()
    player.set_mrl("/media/pi/GROT/MOSA25.mp4")
    player.play()
    sleep(120)
    while player.get_state() in playing:
        sleep(1)
        continue        
    print("Finished")
    sleep(600)
    continue
```

```
# For more options and information see
# http://rpf.io/configtxt
# Some settings may impact device functionality. See link above for details

# uncomment if you get no picture on HDMI for a default "safe" mode
#hdmi_safe=1

# uncomment the following to adjust overscan. Use positive numbers if console
# goes off screen, and negative if there is too much border
#overscan_left=16
#overscan_right=16
#overscan_top=16
#overscan_bottom=16

# uncomment to force a console size. By default it will be display's size minus
# overscan.
#framebuffer_width=1280
#framebuffer_height=720

# uncomment if hdmi display is not detected and composite is being output
#hdmi_force_hotplug=1

# uncomment to force a specific HDMI mode (this will force VGA)
#hdmi_group=1
#hdmi_mode=1

# uncomment to force a HDMI mode rather than DVI. This can make audio work in
# DMT (computer monitor) modes
#hdmi_drive=2

# uncomment to increase signal to HDMI, if you have interference, blanking, or
# no display
#config_hdmi_boost=4

# uncomment for composite PAL
#sdtv_mode=2

#uncomment to overclock the arm. 700 MHz is the default.
#arm_freq=800

# Uncomment some or all of these to enable the optional hardware interfaces
#dtparam=i2c_arm=on
#dtparam=i2s=on
#dtparam=spi=on

# Uncomment this to enable infrared communication.
#dtoverlay=gpio-ir,gpio_pin=17
#dtoverlay=gpio-ir-tx,gpio_pin=18

# Additional overlays and parameters are documented /boot/overlays/README

# Enable audio (loads snd_bcm2835)
dtparam=audio=on

# Automatically load overlays for detected cameras
camera_auto_detect=1

# Automatically load overlays for detected DSI displays
display_auto_detect=1

# Enable DRM VC4 V3D driver
dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d
max_framebuffers=2

# Disable compensation for displays with overscan
disable_overscan=0

[cm4]
# Enable host mode on the 2711 built-in XHCI USB controller.
# This line should be removed if the legacy DWC2 controller is required
# (e.g. for USB device mode) or if USB support is not required.
otg_mode=1

[all]

[pi4]
# Run as fast as firmware / board allows
arm_boost=1

[all]
gpu_mem=156
```

Comment: Please add a photo of the setup when the problem happens.  In particular include the PIR, Pi, and wiring.  Please add a listing of `/boot/config.txt` to your question.

Comment: hi @joan, I edited my question. Images are included and also the config.txt

Comment: Maybe it would be useful if you shared details on the motion sensor itself... a mfr part number, a spec sheet, a link???